# PDO::Fetch_classtype returns std class instead of first argument of sql query

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

```
   $sql = "select classname,id,name,value,description from tablename";
   $query = $this->conn->prepare($sql);
   $query->execute();
   $result = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_CLASS | PDO::FETCH_CLASSTYPE);
   var_dump($result);
```

Result shows stdClassObject
Expected is the classname object (of the particular row)

Basically, am trying to loop through the result, figure out which class the row belongs to and access their getter functions.  Same is achieved if I use the following, but not the solution that works for me.

```
   $sql = "select classname,id,name,value,description from tablename";
   $query = $this->conn->prepare($sql);
   $query->execute();
   $result = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_CLASS, 'MyClass');
   var_dump($result);
```

Now, I can loop through the result and access $result->getId() or $result->getName() etc.  How I can achieve this through PDO::FETCH_CLASSTYPE as the classname is dynamically decided by the row in the result set.

Comment: Are you sure the class is defined? See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9550802/pdofetch-classtype-unexpected-result

Comment: The above code is in index.php and MyClass1.php and MyClass2.php are defined in the same root. Am not sure what scope is talked about in the suggestion link provided.  fetchclass works perfectly, but my classname keeps changing depending on the first column, so I need fetchclasstype to work

Comment: Class names are case-sensitive, are you sure the case is correct in the table?

Comment: Have you loaded `MyClass1.php` and `MyClass2.php`? I'm not sure if `FETCH_CLASSTYPE` will auto-load.

Comment: In general, the site uses autoload to load files.  When I copied the whole class code (as per suggested link provided) into my index.php, it worked.  Strange thing, when I removed class code and explicitly included the class file, does not work again.

Comment: Okay, I could include the file and make it work by correcting namespaces, but can anyone help me achieve this by using autoloading and not explicitly including all the class files that the query might return

Comment: I can't find much information about `FETCH_CLASSTYPE`.

Comment: I just glanced at the source code. It simply looks up the class name to see if it exists, and apparently that doesn't trigger the autoloader.

Comment: @Barmar thanks a ton...I definitely did some progress.  Will post another question with precise autoload and fetchclasstype issue

Comment: I have posted a related question and a workaround for the same.
[Linking if it helps someone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72702679/pdofetchclasstype-doesnot-look-for-autoloaded-classes)