# PDO::FETCHCLASSTYPE doesnot look for autoloaded classes

Tags: php, pdo, autoload

In my *index.php*

```
include 'autoload.php';
//sql code 
while ($result = $list->fetch(PDO::FETCH_CLASS | PDO::FETCH_CLASSTYPE)) {
    echo $class = get_class($result);  //shows stdClass when autoload.php is included
    echo $result->showAttributes();
}
```

The goal is to call the class based on first column from the query result.  If I include the following each class instead of *autoload.php*, I get the desired result.

```
include 'Myclass1.php';
include 'Myclass2.php';
```

How can I avoid including bundles of classes and use autoload feature to make PDO::FETCH_CLASSTYPE work.

*This is my autoload.php*

```
class Autoloader
{
    public static function register()
    {
        spl_autoload_register(function ($class) {
            $file = str_replace('\\', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $class).'.php';
                require $file;           
        });
    }
}
Autoloader::register();
```

**EDIT**
Since there were comments about debugging the autoload, I used FETCH_CLASS, I can load respective classes.  The issue is FETCH_CLASSTYPE is not able to identify the classes from autoload.  I cannot use FETCH_CLASS as the class is decided dynamically.  I have printed the result set and first column is the class names to be autoloaded.

```
while ($result = $list->fetch(PDO::FETCH_CLASS, 'MyClass1')) {
    echo $class = get_class($result);  //shows MyClass1, MyClass2 depending on what is passed to FETCH_CLASS
    echo $result->showAttributes();
}
```

Comment: I am using PDO and do `$sth->fetchObject(Model::class);` where my class is "Model".

Comment: Are you sure the autoloading is working at all? Have you tried to instantiate the classes any other way rather than via PDO? That would help to ensure that PDO is where we should be focusing (or not).

Comment: @ADyson Yes, autoload is working perfectly.  If I mention FETCHCLASS and give Classname explicitly, all the classes objects are instantiated and their methods are called.

Comment: @MarkusZeller I cannot explicitly mention classname and it is dynamically decided by each row first column

Comment: WHY on the Earth everyone is adding this horrendous if (file_exists($file)) { to their autoloader, effectively disabling all the means to debug the autoloading issue? That's really beyond my understanding

Comment: Besides. you should add some debugging output to your autoloading function ini otder to see whether i's called at all

Comment: @YourCommonSense autoload is working perfectly fine.  Somehow fetchclasstype is working only when the file is explicitly included.  Other than fetchclass, everything else works, so am definite about autoload working.

Comment: @YourCommonSense If you stack multiple autoloaders, it might make sense to silently skip classes that don't exist, rather than using a hard `require`, in case another autoloader wants to handle the class.

Comment: That said, you should add some debugging to your autoloader - is it being run for each row of the result? With what argument? You could also show us a sample result set with the *exact* string that's in the first column, and the *exact* class name you want it to map to.

Comment: I have edited my question to answer your comment.  Autoload is working in different parts of the same page.  There is a disconnect between FETCH_CLASSTYPE and autoload, am trying to see someone's insight to workaround

Comment: Just like Barmar told you in the other question, it seems PDO has it's own way to check if the class exists to be able to fall back for the stdClass. Thus effectively preventing the autoload from triggering. If you'll have in your code $classname = (class_exists('foo')) ? 'foo'  : 'stdClass'; it won't trigger the autoload either. Looks like a bug that nobody bothered to fix, probably because nobody is actually using this class loafing magic. TBH, i find all this class loading paraphernalia quite useless. There are always nuances that make you instantiate classes by hand, after reading the row.

Comment: @YourCommonSense thanks a ton.  I stopped bothering about FETCH_CLASSTYPE or FETCH_CLASS and created an instance after reading the row.  Added this as first statement in while loop, $obj = FactoryClass::subClass($result);  Updated the constructor to accept $result parameter and called the setters in it, now I am able to use $obj to call getters to display properties of each independent class.

Comment: That's probably worth posting as an answer...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Posting the workaround based on comments as it might help someone looking for the same.

*In my index.php file*

```
include 'autoload.php';

$object = new Mainclass();
$list = $object->getList();

while ($row = $list->fetch()) {
    $obj = FactoryClass::subClass($row['type'],$row); //read row and instantiate type object
    echo $obj->showAttributes();
}
```

In my *factoryclass* where I create an instance

```
class FactoryClass
{
    public static function subClass($obj = '', $values = [])
    { 
        if (!empty($obj)) { 
            $class = $obj;
        } else {
            $class = 'sampleclass'; //fallback class
        }
        return new $class($values);
    } 
}
```

Updated my class to accept parameters in constructor and called setter in it, so in my MyClass1.php

```
class MyClass1 extends AbstractClass
{
    public function __construct($values = [])
    {
        parent::__construct($values);
        if (!empty($values)) {
            //call setter functions of class attributes
        }
    }
    public function showAttributes()
    {
        //define the display calling getters
    }
}
```

What I wanted is to read a row, create an object based on row result,
send row result to set the properties and use those properties
to display the page content instead of dealing with the query result directly.

Comment: The default value for `$values` in `subClass()` should be an empty array, not a string.

Comment: It would be more general if `subClass()` took a parameter to specify the column name containing the type, rather than hard-coding `$values['type']`.

Comment: @Barmar, but then I wouldnt be able to set some default values through the constructor (new $class($values)).  I can create a SetAttributes function to set all attributes of that particular class and call it after creating the new instance, but I wasn't quite sure if it is better approach

Comment: Why not? `function __constrict($values = [], $column = 'type')`. Then use `$values[$column]` instead of `$values['type']`